# Who have come/came through this pain

Tags: tense

I have seen people use,

> Who have come through this pain.

Instead of,

> Who have came through this pain.

Why even after "have" , "come" is used and not "came" ?

Comment: It's an irregular verb: the present is *come*, the past is *came*, and the past perfect is *come*.

Comment: Seems to me this is OT - dictionaries routinely provide the principal parts of verbs.

Comment: Neither makes sense as is. Sources or more context are needed to better understand your concern, and to explain the correct usage.

Comment: @user3169: Is that a boilerplate "cut&paste" comment? What possible context could affect the fact that OP's first example is perfectly valid English, and the second one is simply ***wrong**?* Just because they're not full sentences doesn't mean they can't be evaluated as fragments which should accord with basic grammar.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why, have you seen me use it before? Anyway I was not judging right or wrong, and I agree the second one is NG. But I would like to see the phrase "Who have come through this pain." as a standalone phrase by itself. Specifically, "who" needs a reference to decide if it is plural (OK) or singular (NG).

Comment: @user3169: I agree it's tiresome when questioners provide so little context. This OP has now asked 20 questions, and should know better. But your comment implies your closevote was for "Unclear" - really the issue is that it's "Too Basic" (unless the OP can show evidence of having looked for an answer but been unable to understand whatever he found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be 'come' because with 'have' we always use third form of verb (i.e. *come* here)

So "Who have come through this pain" is fine.